# How to log all Magento SQL?

Tags: database, magento-1, sql, log, debugging

Is there any easy way to log all query executed by Magento ?

The goal is to print all the SQL executed, for example during page load

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you want to be sure all SQL is actually logged, I suggest to use a third party software:

- [Neon Profile SQL](http://www.profilesql.com/) is actually free and works fine
  ( you need to edit local.xml to attach Magento to Neon ... it works as a kind of SQL proxy logging everything that pass through it)

In alternative a native Magento/Varien approach could be the following one:

1. edit `lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php`
2. change the following properties to `true` (line 103 )
3. you will have a log file to be created here `var/debug/pdo_mysql.log`

Here line to be changed: ( comments are self explanatory )

```
 /**
     * Write SQL debug data to file
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_debug               = true;

    /**
     * Minimum query duration time to be logged
     *
     * @var float
     */
    protected $_logQueryTime        = 0.05;

    /**
     * Log all queries (ignored minimum query duration time)
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_logAllQueries       = true;

    /**
     * Add to log call stack data (backtrace)
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_logCallStack        = true;
```

Log produced are like the following one:

```
## 2014-06-26 12:18:47
## 10258 ## QUERY
SQL: SELECT `adminnotification_inbox`.* FROM `adminnotification_inbox` WHERE (title = 'Customize your order and invoice numbers to protect your sales using Order Number Customizer by XTENTO.') AND (url = 'http://www.xtento.com/magento-extensions/order-number-customizer.html?utm_source=feed&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=order_number_customizer')
AFF: 1
TIME: 0.0008
```

In case you have enabled `$_logCallStack` you will have also a TRACE parte

```
TRACE: #1 Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql#00000000644036ff00007f14137095e6#->_debugStat(2, 'SELECT `adminnot...', array(), &Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql#000000006440371700007f14137095e6#) called at [lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:424]
#2 Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql#00000000644036ff00007f14137095e6#->query(&Varien_Db_Select#000000006440371800007f14137095e6#, array()) called at [lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php:753]
#3 Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql[Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract]#00000000644036ff00007f14137095e6#->fetchRow(&Varien_Db_Select#000000006440371800007f14137095e6#) called at [app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Resource/Inbox.php:116]
#4 Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Resource_Inbox#00000000644034c500007f14137095e6#->parse(&Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Inbox#00000000644034e900007f14137095e6#, array(array('severity' => 4, 'date_added' => '2013-10-23 13:00...', 'title' => 'Customizing your...', 'description' => 'Easily add new c...', 'url' => 'http://www.xtent...'), array('severity' => 4, 'date_added' => '2014-04-09 17:00...', 'title' => 'Customize your o...', 'description' => 'Customize your M...', 'url' => 'http://www.xtent...'), array('severity' => 4, 'date_added' => '2014-05-06 17:00...', 'title' => 'Process orders i...', 'description' => 'Process all your...', 'url' => 'http://www.xtent...'))) called at [app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Inbox.php:118]
#5 Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Inbox#00000000644034e900007f14137095e6#->parse(array(array('severity' => 4, 'date_added' => '2013-10-23 13:00...', 'title' => 'Customizing your...', 'description' => 'Easily add new c...', 'url' => 'http://www.xtent...'), array('severity' => 4, 'date_added' => '2014-04-09 17:00...', 'title' => 'Customize your o...', 'description' => 'Customize your M...', 'url' => 'http://www.xtent...'), array('severity' => 4, 'date_added' => '2014-05-06 17:00...', 'title' => 'Process orders i...', 'description' => 'Process all your...', 'url' => 'http://www.xtent...'))) called at [app/code/local/Xtento/XtCore/Model/Feed.php:57]
#6 Xtento_XtCore_Model_Feed#000000006440348500007f14137095e6#->checkUpdate(&Varien_Event_Observer#00000000644034d900007f14137095e6#) called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:1338]
#7 Mage_Core_Model_App#00000000644036ef00007f14137095e6#->_callObserverMethod(&Xtento_XtCore_Model_Feed#000000006440348500007f14137095e6#, 'checkUpdate', &Varien_Event_Observer#00000000644034d900007f14137095e6#) called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:1317]
#8 Mage_Core_Model_App#00000000644036ef00007f14137095e6#->dispatchEvent('controller_actio...', array('controller_actio...' => &Fishpig_Wordpress_Adminhtml_WordpressController#000000006440364a00007f14137095e6#)) called at [app/Mage.php:451]
#9 Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_actio...', array('controller_actio...' => &Fishpig_Wordpress_Adminhtml_WordpressController#000000006440364a00007f14137095e6#)) called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:528]
#10 Fishpig_Wordpress_Adminhtml_WordpressController[Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action]#000000006440364a00007f14137095e6#->preDispatch() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php:160]
#11 Fishpig_Wordpress_Adminhtml_WordpressController[Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action]#000000006440364a00007f14137095e6#->preDispatch() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:408]
#12 Fishpig_Wordpress_Adminhtml_WordpressController[Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action]#000000006440364a00007f14137095e6#->dispatch('checkVersion') called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php:250]
#13 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Admin[Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard]#00000000644036ae00007f14137095e6#->match(&Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http#000000006440365c00007f14137095e6#) called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:176]
#14 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front#000000006440365700007f14137095e6#->dispatch() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354]
#15 Mage_Core_Model_App#00000000644036ef00007f14137095e6#->run(array('scope_code' => '', 'scope_type' => 'store', 'options' => array())) called at [app/Mage.php:687]
#16 Mage::run('', 'store') called at [index.php:87]
```

Answer (score 15):

Activate the Zend SQL Profiler with the following node in your `app/etc/local.xml`

```
<resources>
 <default_setup>
  <connection>
   <profiler>1</profiler>
```

Then you can access the profiler somewhere in your code and retrieve a lot of informations about all executed queries:

```
$profiler = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write')->getProfiler();
```

To simply output all queries:

```
print_r($profiler->getQueryProfiles());
```

You can add these two lines at the end of `index.php` to see all queries at the bottom of each page. Be aware that this will break AJAX requests that return a JSON response, so you might consider logging the queries instead of printing them, with this code (again, add it at the end of `index.php`):

```
$profiler = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write')->getProfiler();
Mage::log(print_r($profiler->getQueryProfiles(), true), null, 'queries.log', true);
```

Then you will find all queries in `var/log/queries.log`

Don't forget to remove the lines again after you finished debugging!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure this will catch every query, but most run through the query method Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract query method in

> lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php

With that in mind, you could temporarily add some debugging statements (to a copy you make in

> app/code/local/Mage

to be safe)

```
public function query($sql, $bind = array())
{
    // connect to the database if needed
    $this->_connect();

    // is the $sql a Zend_Db_Select object?
    if ($sql instanceof Zend_Db_Select) {
        if (empty($bind)) {
            $bind = $sql->getBind();
        }

        $sql = $sql->assemble();
    }
    echo '$sql' . "\n<br />\n";
    var_dump($bind);
```

Comment: I think I have used a similar approach once but I found more nice the method suggest by me :)

Comment: "temporarily add some debugging statements to be safe".  There is nothing safe in this approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the mysql server and you don't have other projects that run queries, you can try adding the general log from mysql. Look here on how to do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log
because it writes all the queries the log file can get large very fast, so be sure to turn it off after you're done with it.